# How to abbreviate a list of strings to shortest, unambiguous form

Tags: rust

Let's say there is an array of string literals, like so:

```rust
let list = ["apple", "apricot", "banana", "cherry"];
```

You want to abbreviate each of these string literals to its shortest, unambiguous form. With the given input, the output would be:

```rust
["app", "apr", "b", "c"]
```

I think I'll have to iterate over the list, find common start-substrings of the current item and the adjacent ones, though doing 'only' that seems insufficient as it wouldn't work if strings are similar to each other. At least that's what I think.

Comment: Could the people voting to close the question for "Need to focus" explain their reasoning? The question is clear, unambiguous, and on-topic. Algorithmic questions are perfectly fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?!

Answer (score 2):

A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is perfect for that. You can write your own or use an existing library.

Fill the trie with the strings. Then, for each split in the trie, create more strings for each node and keep pushing into them until there are no more splits, then you only need to take one more letter.

For example, from your strings we'll build the following trie:

```
     ple
    /
  ap
 /  \
/    ricot
---- banana
\
 cherry
```

We can then traverse it: "cherry" and "banana" have no splits, so we will just take the first letter. "ap" is shared, so we will traverse further. They don't split anymore, so we will take the shared prefix ("ap") and one letter from each split - resulting in "app" and "apr".

Comment: It seems like a trie could be a helpful data structure for the task at hand, though I am not sure if it is sufficient to get the job done.

I've pushed the 4 example strings into https://docs.rs/trie-rs/latest/trie_rs/
Though, to follow the approach you suggested I would need the ability to take one of the input-strings, e.g. "apple" and get a list of 'splits' or common prefix strings from the data structure, in this case 'ap' and 'ple', though it doesn't seem like that's possible.

Is that a deficiency of the trie_rs implementation?

Comment: @MichaelB.Ortiz You will have to find a library that supports that, or build your own.